# My C program counts characters incorrectly

Tags: c, count, character

Hy everyone, so I wrote some code that should count characters that are typed in console by user, using getchar() and a while loop until EOF character is typed, but it adds more to the *count* variable that it should. For example, I enter 3 characters, and then EOF character(in this case 'z') and at the end It outputs that I entered 6 characters, if I enter 4 chars + 'z' it says 8, if 5 it says 10. It displays x2 number of charaters it should.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define END 'z'

int main()
{
    printf("Hello:\n");
    int count = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != END)
    {
        count++;
    }

    printf("You entered %d charaters.", count);
}
```

Why is that so? :/

Comment: Code seems correct. Are you launching it on a wide char system console? Try using [getwchar](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getwchar.3.html)

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/A2c9hLqK98qb8UQn). Are you sure you entered only 3 characters without any extra characters such as newline characters? Also note that using `char` to store what is returned from `getchar()` is not good because it may return `EOF`, which cannot be stored to `char`.

Comment: you are typing 1[enter]2[enter]3[enter]z[enter]?

Comment: `c` must be of type `int`. `getchar()` returns a value of type `int`. Assigning that value to a variable of type `char` loses information you may need.

Comment: Note that if you indicate 'end of file' before typing the END character (on Unix, by typing control-D; on Windows, by typing control-Z), your code will go into an infinite loop.  You should be using `int c;` (not `char c;`) because `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, and you should be using `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != END)` in the loop condition (or you can test for END and EOF in the other order).  You should always at least consider what happens if you are told EOF at the most inconvenient moment.

Comment: `getchar` doesn't return a `char` (check `man getchar` -> it returns `int`). You might want to make sure `getchar` doesn't return `EOF`, and you probably want to account for `\n` characters, too

Comment: Please show **exactly** what you type for testing. Including any newlines you enter!

Comment: I've changed the code to use `int` in the question, as this is a useful duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you enter a character with getchar() and after that press "enter", you enter one more char which is a newline character.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c=='\n')
        continue;
    count++;
}
```

This will solve your problem.

I have done some tests with your and my code, just to see if that was the problem. The output is here:

output with your code:

```
Hello:
a
s
d
df
You entered 9 charaters.

Hello:
asdf

You entered 5 charaters.
```

output with my code:

```
Hello:
a
s
d
f
You entered 4 charaters
```

Comment: @Mirakurun Yes your code should work even if he is entring '\n' after every character but I guess he is getting error without that.

Comment: I didn't wrote it is wrong, I wrote that at the moment nobody knows if OP press enter key between other chars.

Comment: I checked his code without newline and it seems ok. I posted the output in edit. Asdf\n that's those 5 characters.